# How to generate PDF documentation for my project?

Tags: pdf-generation, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for creating documentation of my project. I am able to create Latex file for my documentation, but how to convert it to pdf. I found in the manual of Doxygen that we need to give a make pdf command in outputdir. I tried this but i used to get following error.

$ make pdf

del /s/y *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out refman.pdf

del: not found

make: *** [clean] Error 127

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you generated the output on a Windows machine, and are now running make from a Unix/Linux machine. This causes your problem.

I suggest to edit the Makefile in the latex output directory and replace "del" by "rm -rf" and then rerun make. Alternatively, you could generate the latex output using the Unix/Linux version of doxygen. Then doxygen will put "rm -rf" in the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

cd /to/your/textpath/.tex

then pdflatex refman.tex

Comment: This is just building the refman.tex once and just gives an impression on how the output will look like. It is not looking at the bibliography (when present) and also does not always give the right  indices (LaTeX -> PDF requires multiple passes), it is better to use make to generate the PDF (and the make.bat / Makefile should nowadays be correct).